# Set build number for conda metadata inside Azure pipeline

Tags: conda-build, azure-devops-pipelines

I am using the bash script to build the conda pakage in azure pipeline `conda build . --output-folder $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` And here is the issue, Conda build uses the build number in the meta.yml file([see here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html)).

A solution of What I could think of is, first, copy all files to `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` and add the Azure pipeline's `Build.BuildNumber` into the meta.yml and build the package to `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` (within a sub-folder)

I am trying to avoid do it by writing shell script to manipulate the yaml file in Azure pipeline, because it might be error prone. Any one knows a better way? Would be nice to read a more elegant solution in the answers or comments.

Comment: Why do you want to change the build number programmatically?  The build number is intended to be incremented when you make changes to the recipe contents, such as the requirements in `meta.yaml` or the commands in `build.sh`.  I don't understand why you want the conda package build number to match the Azure pipelines build number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Azure pipelines. But in general, if you want to control the build number without changing the contents of `meta.yaml`, you can use a `jinja` template variable within `meta.yaml`.

Choose a variable name, e.g. `CUSTOM_BUILD_NUMBER` and use it in `meta.yaml`:

```yaml
package:
  name: foo
  version: 0.1

build:
  number: {{ CUSTOM_BUILD_NUMBER }}
```

To define that variable, you have two options:

- Use an environment variable:

  ```sh
  export CUSTOM_BUILD_NUMBER=123
  conda build foo-recipe
  ```

OR

- Define the variable in `conda_build_config.yaml` [(docs)](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html), as follows

  ```sh
  echo "CUSTOM_BUILD_NUMBER:" >> foo-recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
  echo " - 123"               >> foo-recipe/conda_build_config.yaml   

  conda build foo-recipe
  ```

---

If you want, you can add an `if` statement so that the recipe still works even if `CUSTOM_BUILD_NUMBER` is not defined (using a default build number instead).

```yaml
package:
  name: foo
  version: 0.1

build:
  {% if CUSTOM_BUILD_NUMBER is defined %}
    number: {{ CUSTOM_BUILD_NUMBER }}
  {% else %}
    number: 0
  {% endif %}
```